# Ubuntu 20.04 AMD [free] radeon driver blank 2nd screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

Running a older HD8570D gpu that has a display port and vga on Ubunutu 20.04. At boot up both monitors respond, logo appears on both, but when the desktop comes up, VGA monitor goes into power save and I see this in dmesg:

```
[  605.375130] [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
[  605.375151] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing E4DE (len 2650, WS 0, PS 8) @ 0xEAE6
[  605.533100] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[  605.533135] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
```

Basically I cannot get the dual monitor setup to work.

If I disconnect the monitor and detect-displays, I don't see that dmesg item, reconnect the monitor and detect, the error comes up again. When I do a screenshot of the desktop, I see both displays. Control pane detects/shows both displays too in the config. Just that the VGA monitor goes into power save/stops working.

My config:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

```
Linux 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Dual booted into windows and an old OpenSuse 13 install (old amd fglrx), and dual monitor works fine both cases.

Any ideas to fix? tried amdgpu-pro and it's not compatible with this gpu--won't detect the 2nd monitor.